# how to handle ntml authenication for e2e testing

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, ntlm-authentication, wdio

I am trying to test a page login using nodejs (v18.16.0) and wdio/cli. However, when I hit the website I  am getting a error...

```
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)',
```

using headless chrome v114.

with 'wget' I see NTLM authentication is used and I can access the page fine from my laptop. However, in a ubuntu docker container, I get the error above. How does one authenticate to the server so we can login to the webpage? I tried to use the devtools as described here ([How to add custom header for accessing a page URL and then performing test automation on that page, i am using a webdriverio,mocha,nodejs framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374650/how-to-add-custom-header-for-accessing-a-page-url-and-then-performing-test-autom)), but have not luck.

```
root@0e16ae709c84:/wido# wget --no-check-certificate --server-response -qO /dev/null "https://testsite.com"
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Thu, 06 Jul 2023 07:48:17 GMT
  Content-Length: 1293
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Thu, 06 Jul 2023 07:48:17 GMT
  Content-Length: 1293
```

Any ideas what I am missing ?

```
Config files
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "wido",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.11.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.11.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.11.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chromedriver": "^114.0.2",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.8.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^8.11.2"
  }
}
```

wdio.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    runner: 'local',
    capabilities: [
    {
      maxInstances: 2,
      browserName: "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        args: [
          "--disable-infobars",
          "--window-size=1920,1440",
          "--disable-popup-blocking",
          "--headless",
          "--incognito",
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--ignore-certificate-errors",
          "--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests",
          "--proxy-server=http://proxy.com:80",
          "--disable-gpu"
        ]
      },
      proxy: {
        proxyType: "manual",
        httpProxy: "proxy.com:80",
        noProxy: "127.0.0.1,localhost"
      },
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    },
  ],
  outputDir: 'all-logs',
  logLevel: 'info',
  screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
  services: [
    ['chromedriver', {
        logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log', // default
        outputDir: 'all-logs/driver-logs', // overwrites the config.outputDir
        args: ['--silent']
      }
    ], 
    ['devtools', {
      coverageReporter: {
          enable: true,
          type: 'html', // lcov, json, text
          logDir: 'coverage',
          exclude: [/resources/]
      }
    }]
  ], 
    //
    // ==================
    // Specify Test Files
    // ==================
    // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
    // of the configuration file being run.
    //
    // The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
    // that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
    // worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
    // process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
    //
    // If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
    // then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
    // will be called from there.
    //
    specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ],
    // Patterns to exclude.
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    // ============
    // Capabilities
    // ============
    // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
    // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
    // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
    // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
    //
    // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
    // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
    // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
    // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
    // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
    // from the same test should run tests.
    //
    maxInstances: 10,
    //
    // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
    // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
    // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
    //
    //
    // ===================
    // Test Configurations
    // ===================
    // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
    //
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    //
    // Set specific log levels per logger
    // loggers:
    // - webdriver, webdriverio
    // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
    // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
    // - @wdio/local-runner
    // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
    // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    // logLevels: {
    //     webdriver: 'info',
    //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
    // },
    //
    // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
    // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
    bail: 0,
    //
    // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
    // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
    // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
    // gets prepended directly.
    //
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    // Test runner services
    // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
    // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
    // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
    // Framework you want to run your specs with.
    // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
    //
    // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
    // before running any tests.
    framework: 'mocha',
    //
    // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
    // specFileRetries: 1,
    //
    // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
    // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
    //
    // Whether or not retried spec files should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
    // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
    reporters: ['spec'],

    
    //
    // Options to be passed to Mocha.
    // See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
    //
    // =====
    // Hooks
    // =====
    // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
    // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
    // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
    // resolved to continue.
    /**
     * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     */
    // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise specific service
     * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
     * @param  {string} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {object} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
     * @param  {object} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {object} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialized
     * @param  {object} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
     */
    // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just after a worker process has exited.
     * @param  {string} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {number} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param  {object} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {number} retries  number of retries used
     */
    // onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
     * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {string} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
     */
    // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
     * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
     */
    // before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
     * @param {string} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     */
    // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed before the suite starts
     * @param {object} suite suite details
     */
    // beforeSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
     * Function to be executed before a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) starts.
     */
    // beforeTest: function (test, context) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed _before_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs before calling
     * beforeEach in Mocha)
     */
    // beforeHook: function (test, context) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed _after_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs after calling
     * afterEach in Mocha)
     */
    // afterHook: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    // },
    /**
     * Function to be executed after a test (in Mocha/Jasmine only)
     * @param {object}  test             test object
     * @param {object}  context          scope object the test was executed with
     * @param {Error}   result.error     error object in case the test fails, otherwise `undefined`
     * @param {*}       result.result    return object of test function
     * @param {number}  result.duration  duration of test
     * @param {boolean} result.passed    true if test has passed, otherwise false
     * @param {object}  result.retries   informations to spec related retries, e.g. `{ attempts: 0, limit: 0 }`
     */
    // afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    // },


    /**
     * Hook that gets executed after the suite has ended
     * @param {object} suite suite details
     */
    // afterSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
     * @param {string} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     * @param {number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
     * @param {object} error error object if any
     */
    // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
     * the test.
     * @param {number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
     * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
     * @param {object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
     */
    // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed when a refresh happens.
    * @param {string} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
    * @param {string} newSessionId session ID of the new session
    */
    // onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
    // }
}
```

wdio.js

```
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const assert = require('assert');

describe("Test Scenario", () => {

  it("Navigate to Site", () => {
    let cred = 'user:pass';
    let encodedCredentials = Buffer.from(cred).toString('base64')
    console.log("The encoded base64 string is:", encodedCredentials);
    browser.cdp('Network', 'setExtraHTTPHeaders', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedCredentials}`,
      },
    });
    browser.url("https://testsite.com");
    browser.pause(3000);
  });

  it("Feed in details and initiate login", () => {
    var title = browser.getTitle();
    console.log(title);

    var page = browser.getHTML();
    console.log(page);

    $('#UserName').setValue("test");
    $('#Password').setValue("test");
    $('#btnSubmit').click();
  });

  it("Perform assertions", () => {
    $("//h1[text()='Dashboard']");
    expect($("//p[@class='about-description']").getText()).to.equal(
      "super secret site"
    );
  });

  it("Logout", () => {
    $("//span[@class='display-name']").moveTo();
    $("//a[text()='Log Off']").waitForDisplayed(5000);
    $("//a[text()='Log Off']").click();
    $("//p[contains(text(), 'You are now logged out.')]");
  });
});
```